# C# Winforms: Binding data model to a datagridview row (adding row by row)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I have a winforms app in c# and .NET 3.5 in Visual Studio 2008.

In my form, I have a DataGridView. This datagridview has 8 columns in this order:

- Image : DataGridViewImageColumn
- DateAndTime : DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
- ID : DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
- ID2 : DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
- Name : DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
- Surname : DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
- SecondSurname : DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
- Address : DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

This datagridview is populated row by row, I mean, each time some conditions happens. When those conditions are satisfied, I get an ID and with this ID I perform then a request to database, I call a stored procedure from C# passing it the ID received. The stored procedure do a SELECT (from several tables) for retrieving some data according ID passed.

Once I get the data coming from database (Always one row), I create a new object of type PersonalData which is the following from the dataset received:

```
namespace MyDataModel
{
    public class PersonalData 
    {        
        public DateTime DateAndTime
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string ID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string ID2
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Surname
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string SecondSurname
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Address
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

I populate the Personal data object (ds is of type DataSet):

```
            if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                PersonalData personalData = new PersonalData ()
                {
                    DateAndTime = DateTime.Now, // This value I put manually
                    ID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString().Trim(), // ID
                    ID2 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString().Trim(),          // ID2
                    Name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString().Trim(),          // Name
                    Surname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString().Trim(),  // Surname
                    SecondSurname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString().Trim(),  // Second surname
                    Address = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][5].ToString().Trim()     // Address                     
                };
            }
```

With this PersonalData object popylated, I want to add it to the datagridview as a new row. Note that column image of datagridview is not in the data model, I will add an image or another depending on a condition (a png image).

So how can I do this?

Comment: No where in your posted code are you adding a new row.  You didn't document the DataSource for your grid.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you want to do (add a row to the grid) will depend on how the grids data source is set up assuming it “has” a data source. If the grid does not have a data source then you can simply add a row to the grid. If the grid has a data source, then in most cases you want to add the new row to the data source and not the grid. Your question is missing this important information.